# What does the green dashboard symbol mean on a Toyota vios 2008?

Tags: toyota, warning-light, vios

What does the green dashboard symbol mean on a Toyota vios 2008? When you start the car, this symbol is lighted. After 5 minutes it goes off. I'm guessing this indicates that the engine is still cool and warming up. Should I wait for this to go off before I drive the car? Or no need to wait for this?

The symbol looks like a pole with three flags, and the word "COOL" at the bottom of it, all are in the color green.

Comment: A picture would be very helpful.

Comment: "Green symbol" isn't very specific.  You might look at [the manual](http://www.toyota.com/t3Portal/document/om/OM0832SQG/pdf/2008_Yaris%20Sedan_QRG_lr.pdf), specifically pages 4 and 5, available on [Toyota's site](http://www.toyota.com/owners/web/pages/resources/owners-manuals#Owners-Manuals) to find out what the light means.

Comment: it looks like a pole with three flags, and the word "COOL" at the bottom of it. All are in the color green.

Answer (score 3):

[According to Toyota](http://www.toyota.com/t3Portal/document/om/OM52851U/pdf/sec_2-2.pdf) it's a low engine coolant temperature indicator.

[image]

Looks like they refer to the light in the instructions on what to do when you car overheats

[See page 321 here](http://www.toyota.com/t3Portal/document/om/OM52851U/pdf/sec_5-2.pdf)

[image]

Comment: When you start the car, this symbol is lighted. After 5 minutes it goes off. I'm guessing this indicates that the engine is still cool and warming up. Should I wait for this to go off before I drive the car? Or no need to wait for this?

Comment: @John no need to wait to drive the car.